# SearchView always on top

Tags: android

I wanted to know how you can keep a `SearchView` widget always on top of the screen instead of calling it every time we press the search button.

I've added the `onSearchRequested` to keep it visible by default in my activity but as I transition from one activity to another it returns to its original form i.e appears when the search button is tapped.

How do I keep it visible permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the soln. by simply calling the function again in onResume();

Answer (score 0):

From [android site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546170/searchview-always-on-top) - "An activity represents a single screen with a user interface. ... Although the activities work together to form a cohesive user experience ..., each one is independent of the others.".

So, try adding `SearchView` to `ActonBar`, as specified on [android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView).